# Is maven necessary to create web sockets in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

As i m new to the web sockets i want to clarify that is there any simple methods to create web sockets in java without using maven.
please help me friends.

Comment: Maven is a Build tool and has nothing to do with Web sockets.

Comment: Maven and sockets have nothing in common!

Comment: @BlankChisui: dr could you provide me easy steps to create websockets

Comment: @NarendraPathai: dear please help i m working on eclipse but how to start with scratch i dont know! i know only concepts of websockets

Comment: @NarendraPathai:i had already gone through this url:http://java.dzone.com/articles/jsr-356-java-api-websocket

Comment: It depends on what you want to achive. Implementing something using raw Websockets is the wrong approach most of the time. Espetially if you are new to java.

Comment: @BlankChisui: i agreed with you but i know implementation of sockets in java not web sockets.

Comment: @BlankChisui: I want simple way to implement it with my own business logic

Comment: @noviceCodder: I can understand that, but if you are already in a state of such confusion that you think Maven is used to actually develop stuff, you are not in a position to actually be able to do that with all the help in the world. You need to take a few steps back and gain better understanding of this thing called Java you're using.

Comment: @Gimby: dear u r right, here i m not concern to create my projects in maven , for this i followed this tutorial:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/ please help me how to create websockets in java thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be different ways to create web sockets,but if your question is whether you can create web sockets without including maven as a build ,then the answer is yes.
but let me clarify maven is not the one which you need to create web sockets,its just a build tool.

For better understanding ,go through following link

http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials/

Comment: @Chales_Stevens: thanks dr but its all about maven i want any simple code that can help me to know basics of websockets.

Comment: Use this link for reference https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-websocketapi.html  ,and maven is totally different it only for building ,cleaning etc your project,it is helpful when there is large projects with many classes,and if you are facing problem with maven project,trying developing your project without maven.

Comment: :thanks , instead of using glass fish server can i use tomcat with eclipse indigo?

Comment: Well tomcat is a web server and glassfish is application server,but yes you can.

Comment: i m using eclipse indigo , but this document demos are in netbeans so can i use eclipse indigo??

Comment: yes you can developement of project can be done in any of the IDE

Comment: @ Charles Stevens:dr could provide me the link where i can download websockets  api jar file reply asap.

Comment: try these links::     https://code.google.com/p/unitt/downloads/detail?name=websocket-0.9.3.jar&can=2&q=                                                              http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgrizzlywebsocketsjar.htm